# Answer the call of prayer(Adan(azan)) for female

Tags: islamic-philosophy, islamic-basis, islamic-scholar

When I sit with my papa at the time of azan I noticed he read some kalma after every line of azan . I know its blessing for Muslims. Another thing islam not permit women's to recite azan is Islam gave her permission to read these kalma after azan ?

Comment: There's no difference between men and women in worship matters unless it is clearly declared.